# md-divider is not showing up in the md-list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, mean-stack

I have used md-list for listing a few products. The documentation says, md-divider shows a separation line after each row. I have used the code as directed by the documentation however it's not showing the divider. What am I doing wrong?

**CODEPEN**: https://codepen.io/wingoku/pen/zNGxKK

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" layout="column" layout-align="center center" style="min-height: 300px;" class="selectdemoValidations" ng-app="MyApp">
      <md-list>
            <md-list-item layout="row" class="md-2-line"
                          ng-repeat="word in wordsList track by $index">
                  <div layout="row" layout-align="start center" class="md-list-item-text"
                       >
                    <h3>{{word}}</h3>
                  </div>
                  <md-button layout-align="end end" class="md-fab md-mini md-primary"
                             flex="none"
                             ng-click="">x
                  </md-button>

                  <md-divider></md-divider>
            </md-list-item>
         </md-list>
</div>


angular.module('MyApp')
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.wordsList = ["hello world", "one two three", "x y z"]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `layout="row"` from your `md-list-item`.